# Differential Equation. Need to find integrating factor to make it exact.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently doing my pre-u and during one of my maths coursework (MathsIA), I ended up with this differential equation. I need to find y in term of x. This is clearly beyond my syllabus. I managed to manipulate the equation to get u= Mdx + Ndy, which can be solve using exact. However, I fail to find the integrating factor to make it exact, because of the square root. How do I solve this differential equation?

[image]

Comment: Homework, eh? Hint: cross multiply so that you have a function of x equal to a function of y. Then integrate each side.